# How to enforce that HTTP client uses conditional requests for updates?

Tags: http, rest

In a (proper [RMM](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) level 3) RESTful HTTP API, I want to enforce the fact that clients should make conditional requests when updating resources, in order to avoid the [lost update problem](http://www.w3.org/1999/04/Editing/). **What would be an appropriate response to return to clients that incorrectly attempt unconditional PUT requests?**

I note that the (abandoned?) [mod_atom](http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2007/06/25/mod_atom) returns a `405 Method Not Allowed` with an `Allow` header set to `GET, HEAD` ([view source](http://code.google.com/p/mod-atom/source/browse/trunk/src/mod_atom.c?r=59#652)) when an unconditional update is attempted. This seems slightly misleading - to me this implies that PUT is never a valid method to attempt on the resource. Perhaps the response just needs to have an entity body explaining that `If-Match` or `If-Unmodified-Since` must be used to make the `PUT` request conditional in which case it would be allowed?

Or perhaps a `400 Bad Request` with a suitable explanation in the entity body would be a better solution? But again, this doesn't feel quite right because it's using a `400` response for a violation of application specific semantics when [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1) says (my emphasis):

> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed **syntax**.

But than again, I think that using `400 Bad Request` for application specific semantics is becoming a widely accepted pragmatic solution (citation needed!), and I'm just being overly pedantic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following [Jan's request for clarification](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2011JulSep/0515.html) on 27th September 2011, the HTTPbis working group [published a new *Internet-Draft*](http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-nottingham-http-new-status-02.txt) on 18th October 2011, with the brand new **`428 Precondition Required`** status, specifically to address the situation described in my question.

As of April 2012, this is now published as [**RFC 6585**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585) (Additional HTTP Status Codes - an update of [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (HTTP/1.1)). Full quote of [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-3):

> **428 Precondition Required**
>
> The 428 status code indicates that the origin server requires the
> request to be conditional.
>
> Its typical use is to avoid the "lost update" problem, where a
> client    GETs a resource's state, modifies it, and PUTs it back to
> the server,    when meanwhile a third party has modified the state on
> the server,    leading to a conflict.  By requiring requests to be
> conditional, the    server can assure that clients are working with
> the correct copies.
>
> Responses using this status code SHOULD explain how to resubmit the
> request successfully.  For example:
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 428 Precondition Required
> Content-Type: text/html
>
> <html>
>    <head>
>       <title>Precondition Required</title>
>    </head>
>    <body>
>       <h1>Precondition Required</h1>
>       <p>This request is required to be conditional;
>       try using "If-Match".</p>
>    </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Responses with the 428 status code MUST NOT be stored by a cache.

Prior to the introduction of this new status code, [Julian Reschke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50543/julian-reschke) (a member of the HTTPbis working group) [had recommended](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/rest-discuss/message/13202) using a **`403 Forbidden`** for the situation that is now covered by `428`.

Comment: "428 Precondition Required" is out: http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-nottingham-http-new-status-02.txt . Cool!

Comment: @Jan That is cool indeed! I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks for keeping an eye out and coming back here to update us :)

Comment: RFC 6585 is now published with this in. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

To my best knowledge, this is not properly defined.

I requested clarification: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2011JulSep/0515.html

Comment: Wow thanks. I'll keep on eye on the list for any recommendations. RFC 2616++ should be worth the wait :)

Comment: Good work. The clarification is now out as RFC 6585. I've updated and accepted my answer with the full info. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If your protocol uses unconditional PUTs for creating resources, then I would interpret the unconditional PUT as a create, not an update. Since the resource already exists, I'd return whatever error you return in that case. (409 Conflict?)

Comment: Interesting suggestion thanks. But wouldn't this violate the idempotent nature of `PUT`? Multiple identical requests should have the same result as a single request. So the second unconditional `PUT` should also succeed.

Comment: Plus, in my case, `POST`s to "collection" resources are made to create new resources (the server is in charge of the URLs assigned) and `PUT`s cannot create new resources (because the client would have to know the URL to `PUT` the new resource to, but it doesn't)

Comment: If the request is identical, it should succeed.